# How can I use plaintext when a regular expression is the only option?

Tags: regex

I notice that some programs (like xdotool for instance) absolutely require a regular expression for searching. Is there something more clever one can do except figuring out what the dialect of the regular expression you are faced with and escaping anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way... you already partly answered your question. What you *can* do is use a small script that auto-escapes everything needed based on the dialect so you don't have to do this manually. Search here at SO, there are small sed scripts to do that.